# Printing all the id names for a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I want print the Id of every element that has the class name "test". Right now nothing is printing. I would like this to print

```
myAnchor
SecondId
```

I left my comments in there to show how an Id can be printed by accessing the Id name

This is my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a id="myAnchor" class="test" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">W3Schools</a></p>
<p><a id="SecondId" class="test" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Second</a></p>

<p>Click the button to display the value of the id attribute of the link above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    //var x = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.id;
    var x = document.getElementByClassName("test");
    for(count = 0; count < x.length; count++){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.id;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test");` And also `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[count].id;`

Comment: Might need `...innerHTML += ...` to concatenate all the IDs.

Comment: You're overwriting `demo` every iteration. Also, use `var` in a for loop or you create an implicit global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just got a couple of basic typos:

- `document.getElementByClassName("test")` should be `document.getElementsByClassName("test')`
- `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.id` should be `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x[count].id`

This is because the `getElementsByClassName` function returns an array of elements, so you need to get each element from the array, not the array itself.

Also, you were overwriting `demo` every time. Using the `+=` operator rather than the `=` operator concats an string to the end of the original, rather than setting the original to the new string.

Comment: I won't downvote because downvoting correct answers isn't good, but if the answer to a question is a typo, it really should be closed instead.

Comment: if only questions with upvoted answers would be eligible for auto-deletion after a period of time...

Answer (score 1):

A few changes here:

1. Use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (instead of getElementByClassName, which isn't a function - unless you are defining it somewhere).
2. In order to access the id attribute of the element in the *for* loop, use `x[count].id`, since x is a NodeList and we need to access the element *at index **count***. But for a simpler approach, use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (along with [function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), since the list of elements is a [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instead of a native [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instance) to iterate over the list of elements. That way the *id* attribute can be obtained via `element.id` instead of indexing into the array of elements manually. Also, you don't have to worry about incrementing the loop variable.

   ```
   var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(testElements, function(element) {
       //access elements via callback argument element
   });
   ```

   As it is written with the *for* loop, you would need to access `x[count].id` in order to obtain the value of the *id* attribute.
3. Get a reference to the element with id *demo* outside the loop, then refer to that when adding to the innerHTML property.

   ```
   var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
   //in loop - refer to demo - e.g. demo.innerHTML
   ```

   That way it won't be obtaining a reference to the DOM element each time it adds the id attribute value.
4. Add (append) to the innerHTML ([string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) property using the [plus-equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) operator (i.e. `+=`).

   ```
   demo.innerHTML += element.id;
   ```

   And you might likely want to separate those values (e.g. with a space, [break tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) (i.e. `<br />`), etc.

   ```
       demo.innerHTML += element.id + '<br />';
   ```

See the changes implemented below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(testElements, function(element) {
    demo.innerHTML += element.id+'<br />';
  });
}
```

```html
<p><a id="myAnchor" class="test" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">W3Schools</a>
</p>
<p><a id="SecondId" class="test" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Second</a>
</p>


<p>Click the button to display the value of the id attribute of the link above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `forEach` vs. `for` is negligible and doesn't answer OPs question.

Comment: See reasoning for this in updated explanation - point #2